# Cannot submit a form to back-end

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I would like to submit a form that has a field to upload a file. When I click on the submit button nothing happens.

I read following articles but could not resolve the issue. [1](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multiple-file-upload-example/), [2](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/)

My front-end and back-end codes are as following.

```
<form:form action="${url}profile/edit" method="post"
                                modelAttribute="profile" role="form"
                                enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="photo">Photo</label> <input type="file"
                                        name="photo" class="form-control" id="photo">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-form">
                                        <a class="shape-arrow" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><span></span></a>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title"
                                            class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown"
                                            autocomplete="off">
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="title">
                                            <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Male</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Female</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="firstName">First Name</label> <input type="text"
                                        name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label> <input type="text"
                                        name="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span> <input type="email"
                                            id="email" name="email" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="Enter email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <button class="btn btn-action btn-save">Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </form:form>
```

**Profile**

```
public class Profile {
    private MultipartFile photo;
    private String title;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    getters and setters

}
```

**RequestHandler**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editProfile(
            @ModelAttribute("profile") Profile profile, Model model) {
        System.err.println("in profile/edit" + profile);
        return "profile";
    }

}
```

I added 'Type' attribute to 'Button' but cannot submit the form yet.

```
 <button class="btn btn-action btn-save" type="submit">Save</button>
```

Also, I changes button to input to no avail.

```
 <input class="btn btn-action btn-save" type="submit">Save</input>
```

Comment: If I am not missing something, I don't see <input type="submit"> button in your jsp

Comment: @ankidaemon I added type attribute but cannot submit the form yet. Question is updated.

Comment: The issue is with your jsp only. Either you are missing some tag or having syntax error. I assume the "form" is spring framework tag, if yes then you need to use this form to all input tags like <form:input ... excluding the submit button. See this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html